# set_exception_handler() not catching exceptions

Tags: php, exception

I am building the basics of my error reporting system, basically I have these two bad boys set up

```
class System {
    public function __construct(){
        set_exception_handler(array($this, 'handleExceptions'));
        set_error_handler(array($this, 'handleGenericError'));
    }

    public function handleExceptions(\Exception $e){
        echo "<pre>".print_r($e, true)."</pre>";
    }

    public function handleGenericError($no, $msg, $file, $line, $context){
        $msg .= ' in ['.$file.'] on line ['.$line.']';
        throw new \Exception($msg);
    }
}
```

Then I provoke an error in the `__construct` method, after the declarations. Statements like

```
public function __construct(){
    ....
    echo $undefined_variable;
}
```

And

```
public function __construct(){
    ....
    echo $this->undefined_variable;
}
```

Seem to go well, printing a nice readable exception message, but if I do this

```
public function __construct(){
    ....
    echo $this->$undefined_variable;
}
```

I get an uncaught exception. Why is that? The exception being thrown is from the `handleGenericError` method, I can tell because it has `[]` around it and stuff. This is a little confusing. `:/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem—as I see it—is this:

```
public function __construct(){
    ....
    echo $this->$undefined_variable;
}
```

Will most likely result in:

```
echo $this->[null];
```

When you do assignment like `$this->$undefined_variable` I believe PHP parses that as **“Assign the value of the variable `$undefined_variable` to the are it is placed in right after `$this->`.”** Meaning it’s not even getting to the handler because 100% of nothing is there. It’s simply a null value. It is as if you called:

```
echo $this->;
```

Which is a larger program logic failure because all an exception handler does is catch errors that successfully get to it. A call to `$this->` is a fundamental logic failure outside of the scope of the class & the exception handler within it. You can read up on [how exception handlers in PHP work here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

Comment: But it being such a larger program logic failure, how does it manage to throw the exception?